# Is it possible to create a mysql trigger that inserts the rows of a table to another table at a specific time of day?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am quite new to MySQL and I was wondering if I can make a trigger that inserts all the rows of a table to another table at a specific time. I tried to look at other solutions but it doesn't solve my dilemma. Is there any way that I can automatically add rows to another table on a specific time without generating a mysql query? Answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the [Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html) can be of use.